# Vuejs - Issue when removing a component via directives and the mounted/created event is being executed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I wanted my directive to work as v-if since in my directive I have to check access rights and destroy the element if it does not have access.

Here is my code

```
Vue.directive('access',  {
    inserted: function(el, binding, vnode){

        //check access

        if(hasAccess){
           vnode.elm.parentElement.removeChild(vnode.elm);
        }
    },

});
```

vue file

```
<my-component v-access='{param: 'param'}'>
```

The issue is that i'm applying this directive to a component, it's removing the component but not the execution of functions called by the created/mounted hook.

In the component(my-component) there are functions in mounted/created hook. The execution of these functions are done and I don't want these functions to be executed. Is there a way to stop execution of the mounted/created events?

Comment: could you wrap the code in the mounted and created in an `if` block so if your condition is not met, the code is not executed while the component is destroyed

Comment: You shouldn't use a directive to do this. Directives cannot prevent a component from being created in the first place (`v-if` isn't a real directive).

Comment: Very helpful info. https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/
I faced the same problem and even forceUpdate didn't solve my problem. In my case key-changing strategy helped)

Comment: @DecadeMoon, ok, I have to do something global which I can apply to every components throughout the application. Do you have an idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to replicate the behavior of `v-if` in a custom directive. Directives cannot control how vnodes are rendered, they only have an effect on the DOM element it is attached to. (`v-if` is special, it's not actually a directive but instead generates conditional rendering code when the template is compiled.)

Though I would avoid doing any of the following suggestions if possible, I'll provide them anyway since it's close to what you want to do.

### 1. Extend the Vue prototype to add a global method

You definitely need to use `v-if` to do the conditional rendering. So all we have to do is come up with a global helper method which calculates the access permission.

```js
Vue.prototype.$access = function (param) {
  // Calculate access however you need to
  // ("this" is the component instance you are calling the function on)
  return ...
}
```

Now in your templates you can do this:

```vue
<my-component v-if="$access({ param: 'param' })">
```

### 2. Define global method in the root component

This is basically the same as #1 except instead of polluting the Vue prototype with garbage, you define the method only on the root instance:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  methods: {
    access(param) {
      return ...
    }
  }
})
```

Now in your templates you can do this:

```vue
<my-component v-if="$root.access({ param: 'param' })">
```

Now it's clearer where the method is defined.

### 3. Use a global mixin

This may not be ideal, but for what it's worth you can investigate the viability of a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin).

### 4. Use a custom component

You can create a custom component (ideally functional but it needn't be) that can calculate access for specific regions in your template:

```js
Vue.component('access', {
  functional: true,
  props: ['param'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    // Calculate access using props as input
    const access = calculateAccess(ctx.props.param)

    // Pass the access to the default scoped slot
    return ctx.scopedSlots.default(access)
  }
})
```

In your templates you can do this:

```vue
<access :param="param" v-slot="access">
  <!-- You can use `access` anywhere in this section -->
  <div>
    <my-component v-if="access"></my-component>
  </div>
</access>
```

Since `<access>` is a functional component, it won't actually render it's own component instance. Think of it more like a function than a component.

A bit overkill for your situation, but interesting nonetheless if you ever have a more complicated scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these solutions, it really helps. :)